Clarification Needed: Patent Scope and Prior Art for Auto-Injector Mechanism Design
I've been working on a device with a mechanism similar to these auto-injectors:
https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/applications/29124543/ifw/docs?application=
https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/applications/29481525
It features a hollow barrel with a spring-actuated cylinder inside. When a button is pressed, the cylinder moves forward, with an external component traveling along a slit in the barrel.
The patents for the auto-injectors mention "ornamental design":
https://image-ppubs.uspto.gov/dirsearch-public/print/downloadPdf/D446579
https://image-ppubs.uspto.gov/dirsearch-public/print/downloadPdf/D748243
My questions are:

Are these patents covering the mechanism itself, or just the design/layout of the auto-injector?

Can anyone provide examples of similar devices with a spring-actuated cylinder and side, external mounts to help determine if this concept is novel?


Thank you.

The cited documents are design patents. Design patents cover the ornamental design of functional objects, not the mechanisms. So long as you device doesn't copy the "look" of the ones in the design patents drawings you shouldn't have an issue with the cited documents. This is not to say that there aren't other patents, especially utility patents that are relevant and represent prior art.
As for whether your concept is novel, you really should not disclose anything about it publicly until you have a patent application filed. Otherwise you risk disclosure and thus invalidating your own invention. You need to do a thorough prior art search which takes time and effort. You shouldn't expect others to do this for free especially since we don't know what your invention is. You can hire a patent attorney or agent if you want an authoritative opinion on patentability.
